# python: truncate fractional digits from iso 8601 string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a quick way to truncate the microsecond part, down to 6 digits in an iso date-time string?

For example if the input is:

```
date = '2019-01-09T15:26:23.623349123+01:00'
```

I'd like output to be:

```
date = '2019-01-09T15:26:23.623349+01:00'
```

I have done this using string.index() but resulting code is quite ugly.

Comment: do you mean `outdate = date[:26]+date[29:]` ?

Comment: @Pynchia that might not work because number of fractional digits could change

Comment: then get the last six chars with `date[-6:]` instead. Oh, I see, it has been recommended already yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
from dateutil import parser

k = parser.parse('2019-01-09T15:26:23.623349123+01:00').isoformat()
print(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with simple string operations.

If the length is greater than 32, you want to keep the 26 first characters and the 6 last ones.

In Python if gives:

```
def reformat(dat):
    if len(dat) > 32:
        return dat[:26] + dat[-6:]
```